# Overview of settings option in .NET 6

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-6.0

I'm currently not very satisfied with the way I configure my application on C# .NET 6.

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration library and write every configuration in the appsettings.json file. which leads to a very large file. It is also very heavy to handle as configurations are used in a lot of assemblies.
My first issue due to the amount of packages has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73933398/any-good-practice-regarding-configuration-management) :having a section per assemblies will probably ease the management a lot. (my assemblies generally require an Iconfiguration in their constructor)

When looking for solutions in C#, I come across an issue : finding up to date information ! most answer I find are quite old and it is difficult to know if it is still good practices today in .NET 6.

It seems appsettings.json is the most wildly spread. at least for configuration that does not completely break the code if not properly set.

I found that I can set properties in Settings.settings in visual studio. **Is it common practice ? for what kind of configuration ? Any advantages of using that instead of appsettings.json ?**

**Is there any other recommended way in .NET 6 ? for what specific application ?**

**where do you put settings that are sensitive and not often changed on the scope of the application ?** (example: register numbers in some hardware that the application needs and that are not likely to change after commissioning )

Comment: I have not asked that in your previous question on the topic but will for this one - any particular reason you prefer to inject `IConfiguration` instead of using more idiomatic approach leveraging build in configuration binder  and injecting only relevant configuration already parsed to classes?

Comment: Actually, If I understand properly, what you suggest is : Creating a configuration class for each assembly and create it with the configuration file in the base application. this seems like a good solution ! I guess for the configuration that are not likely to change I could just preset them and simply allow the configuration file to override them.

Comment: Yes, it can be one file or multiple ones, cause you can have nested json objects inside the appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiomatic approach to manage settings (especially with DI) is to use [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (which allows different scenarios including for example monitoring changes of config file):

```cs
// inject, will bind data from config providers 
builder.Services.Configure<SomeServiceSpecificSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("PathToSomeServiceSpecificSettings"));

// use
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly SomeServiceSpecificSettings _options;

    public SomeService(IOptions<SomeServiceSpecificSettings> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Ideally you should not care about `IConfiguration` inside your library - you should care only about the specific settings which should be passed to it and how it will be handled usually should be handled by library consumer.

As for sensitive settings - there are multiple approaches, in some cases environment variables are used, in some - secure key storages, integrated with the build in configuration pipeline (via configuration providers).

The documentation pretty extensively covers this:

- [Configuration in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration)
- [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a good solution ! I don't use ASP.NET but the principle seems applicable.

Comment: @Phaynix yes, the principle is applicable, especially if your library will be consumed with the DI.